# Google Drive Implementation to Android app and Downloading the file from Google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Drive Quick-start App example  works for only uploading files from Android Device to user account. I want to download the files from Gdrive to android app. any help will be appreciated.

I want exact reverse process of this Demo example https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android (download it from Gdrive)

Comment: hello bro.... i am using same code from demo example Quickstart-android....but i have error with com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult import from google play services lib...can you help me so i can use tyhis given code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two steps to download file contents from Drive. First, retrieve the file's metadata and a downloadUrl for the file:

```
// retrieve metadata
File file = drive.files().get(fileId).execute();
```

And, make an authenticated request to the downloadUrl:

```
// download contents a
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl());
HttpResponse response = drive.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(url).execute();
String contents = new Scanner(response.getContent()).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```