# Is there any options available to play video files saved in drive in an android application?

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-drive-api

I am trying to develop an app that play videos from google drive in android app.I want to play and download if i like the video.Is there any way to do this?Also does only 3gp format only be played and what about other formats like mp4,avi etc.. ?? I have also searched about this and i cannot understand these,

[Google Drive Implimentation to android app and Downloading the file from Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921672/google-drive-implimentation-to-android-app-and-downloading-the-file-from-google)

PS:Also want to know how to upload files to a server and view them in android app.
Please help me with this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Android based Google Drive api are still in an infancy when it comes to streaming videos from Drive itself, also what you get from meta data is a 'downloadUrl' which is temporary in nature and when used to store it in DB for further use can lead to SSLException upon expiration of the downloadUrl. so the answer to your requirement is unfortunately no at the moment. Google team is thriving to provide the streaming video support in the near future.

Also with regards with file type, google drive supports any file type obviously a chrome app registered in parallel with google drive must support the same file type by its mimetype for playing the file, but in regards with Android, we have to be content with the supported media types as provided in the [Supported Media in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

In the case of Uploads, google tries to give a ground level implementation in its documentation as [Manage Uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads). But when you look for the same in apis, they are provided in a much encapsulated way and are automatically done just by an insert !

For further information please look into the google documentation.